# Contact terms in Schwinger-Dyson equation and Ward-identity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, definition, ward-identity

I am reading [Weigand's notes](http://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/624b/WeigandQFT.pdf) for the derivation of Ward-identity.

The Second last paragraph on page 133, says the following statement

> "The Schwinger-Dyson equation and the Ward-identity show that the classical equation of motion and current conservation hold inside the correlation functions only up to so-called **contact terms**, which
> are precisely the extra terms we pick up if the insertion point $x$ of the operator $\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}$ or $\partial_\mu j^\mu(x)$ coincides with the insertion point $x_j$ of one of the other fields inside the correlator."

I do not understand the "contact terms".

Can anyone show me explicitly what exactly are these? and What is their mathematical/physical definition?

Feel free to refer any equation from these notes.

Comment: How thorough of an answer are you looking for here? The contact terms are in the sum in the second term of (5.45) of Weigand's notes.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of it. 
Example : What will be the contact terms in case the sum goes from j = 1 to 3 ???

Comment: Is the notation confusing you? What the sum is saying is replace the $j$'th field operator with what's between the $...$'s. It is schematically identical to the product rule.

Comment: When you have points $x$ and $y$ a contact term is something that behaves as $\delta(x,y)$. It is called contact term because it vanishes when $x\neq y$. More rigorously the distribution is non-zero only when $x$ is integrated over a set containing $y$ and the result doesn’t change as you shrink the set to be as small as you want, so long as it still contains $y$.